# Java: Request body in XML or JSON without using String

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, http

I am developing an application using Spring Boot (with Java).
This application has to call several external services and each of these services **requires a complicated body (in json or xml)** (this input can vary! The fields I pass to it are not required so sometimes I might even pass a subset of these fields). These are examples of inputs that services can receive:

```
{
  "field1": "string",
  "field2": "string",
  "field3": "string",
  "field4": 0,
}

<input>
    <input1>my_string</input1>
    <input2>my_string</input2>
</input>
```

I use RestTemplate to make HTTP calls. This is an example. I use a Java String to model the HTTP body (but it has the big defect that **it is not editable but hard-coded**!):

```
    String Jsonbody = "{\r\n"
            + "  \"field1\": \""+myString1+"\"\r\n" 
            + "  \"field2\": \""+myString2+"\"\r\n"
            + "}";

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(Jsonbody, headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<MyResponseClass> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, MyResponseClass.class);
```

It is very bad to have a body hard-coded like this in the `JsonBody` variable. What is the way to have an object in which I **dynamically insert strings** and which automatically creates a JSON object (which I can then convert to a string to put in the .postForEntity method)? The same issue for XML input types.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple libraries as **Gson** or **Jackson** that actually allow you to work with JSON as they are Java Objects to finally serialize them as a body.

If you want to give it a try, you would just need to include **Gson** as dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you'd have to create a POJO for your `POST` body:

```
public class JsonBody {

  private List<String> fields = new LinkedList<>();

  void addField(String field) {
    fields.add(field);
  }

}
```

And feel free to add as many `String` as you want that it will be parsed afterwards.

```
JsonBody jsonBody = new JsonBody();
Gson gson = new Gson();

jsonBody.addField(myString1);
jsonBody.addField(myString2);

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(gson.toJson(jsonBody), headers);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<MyResponseClass> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, MyResponseClass.class);
```

---

This would set your JSON to:

```
{
  fields: [
    contentMyString1,
    contentMyString2
  ]
}
```

Taking the previous example into account, you can just modify and format your JSON as you want in the form of a POJO and use the `Gson::toJson(String)` function from **Gson**.

Of course if you just create a POJO as:

```
public class JsonBody {

  private String field1;
  private String field2;
  private String field3;
  private Integer field4;

}
```

Then the output would be the same one than you have in your initial example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ObjectMapper` class like this ...

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Car car = new Car("yellow", "renault");
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("target/car.json"), car);
```

The output will be

```
{"color":"yellow","type":"renault"}
```

Here's some more data on the topic https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial

Same approach is used for mapping objects into XML (https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-xml-serialization-and-deserialization)

Comment: `ObjectMapper` isn't a class included by default in the JDK, so it would be nice if you include in your answer the dependency you're referring to (which in this case is `jackson-databind` but that's not something that the readers need to know). Also explicitly the question asks how to generate the JSON as a String in order to use it as a POST body, not to write it into a file (which can be acomplished with the `ObjectMapper::writeValueAsString` function, but again the readers don't need to know that).